# oncomplete doesn't fire on a4j:commandButton when using webflow render tag

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2.2, spring-webflow-2

Using spring-webflow 2.4.1 and richfaces 4.5.4 with jsf reference implementation 2.2.10.

I've created a simple form with one a4j:commandButton to reproduce the issue.  The action on the command button calls a transition in the webflow flow.    There is a render tag on the transition to rerender a panel.  The oncomplete doesn't fire.  If I comment out or delete the render, the oncomplete fires.  This of course has the drawback of not rerendering the panel.  Using logging, I've verified the BobBean.changeShowStuff() is called with or without render.

Here's the xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
        <h:head/>
        <h:body>
                <h:panelGroup id="bobPanel" layout="block">
                        <h:outputText value="bob was here" rendered="#{bean.showStuff}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:form id="bobForm">
                        <a4j:commandButton id="btnSubmitQuery"
                                        oncomplete="alert('bob')"
                                        value="Submit Query"
                                        action="reportData"/>
                </h:form>
        </h:body>

</html>
```

the flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated 4/17/2012 21:49:55 by FreeMarker 2.3.16 -->
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="bean" class="BobBean" />
        <view-state id="bob">
                <transition on="reportData">
            <evaluate expression="bean.changeShowStuff()" />
<!--             <render fragments="bobPanel"/>  -->
                </transition>

        </view-state>
</flow>
```

and the backing bean:
import java.io.Serializable;

public class BobBean implements Serializable {

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean showStuff = false;

    public boolean isShowStuff() {
            return showStuff;
    }

    public void changeShowStuff() {
            showStuff = !showStuff;
    }
```

}

How can I get the render in webflow and the oncomplete in richfaces to work on the same commandButton?

Edit: Here's the response bodies returned from the server when clicking the actionButton.

With the render tag in the flow (I added new lines):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1"><changes>
<update id="bobPanel"><![CDATA[<div id="bobPanel">bob was here</div>]]></update>
<update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[e1s1]]></update>
</changes></partial-response>
```

Without the render tag in the flow:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1"><changes>
<update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[e2s1]]></update>
<extension id="org.richfaces.extension">
<complete>alert('bob');</complete></extension>
</changes></partial-response>
```

So, the complete section is missing if the render tag is in the flow.  Before upgrading webflow (2.0 to 2.4), JSF (1.2 to 2.2), and richfaces (3.3 to 4.5) the oncomplete was working.

Comment: When you say "The oncomplete doesn't fire" what does that mean exactly? Are you receiving the rendered html response back from the server for "bobPanel", or receiving a blank response, what is the http status? (Use a sniffing tool like tamper to see what the exact response body is). So if you are receiving a response body with the html contents of "bobPanel" that means webflow did its job but your view layer is not configured properly to handle this rendered fragment.

Comment: I am not familiar with jsf 2.2 or rich faces but my suspicion is the oncomplete="alert('bob')" needs specific conditions to fire (maybe entire page to reload?)  and when used with partial fragment rendering of spring webflow these required conditions are not triggered. I would recommend you step into the view code (jsf or rich faces) and try to isolate exactly what the required conditions are that trigger the oncomplete to fire.

Comment: @Airduster there are no special conditions to fire it, the page needs to contain RichFaces JavaScript so that response can be processed. I do not know what `<render>` does though, if it triggers some other JS then it's possible it prevents proper handling of the response.

Comment: <Render> just sends back rendered html of the fragment in the response body so the response might look like <div id="panelGroup"><div>etc...</div></div> instead of full page<html>..</html>. It is upto your view framework to update via javascript for that "panelGroup" portion of the page Which is what the "oncomplete" attribute/param is suppose to do. So I think your issue is not with webflow but with how a4j is handling this partial response webflow is sending your a4j view framework. I suspect "oncomplete" only exe when javascript document ready event is fired...which is not fired for partial

Comment: According to the docs. "The oncomplete event attribute invokes the event listener after the Ajax response has been returned and the DOM tree of the browser has been updated." <render> does not update the DOM Tree of the browser it just returns partially rendered html in the response. It is upto the receiving javascript client to update the DOM. Reference: http://tinyurl.com/pnrhu8c

Comment: See also:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-faces.html see (13.7.4. Handling Ajax Events In JSF)

Comment: @Airduster if you don't `@` me I don't notice your reply ;). I need implementation spec, is <render> adding to the original response? The oncomplete code is inside the response, not on the page, so it looks like something is happening to that response and RichFaces can't read it.

Comment: @Makhiel I am not familiar enough with richfaces or jsf to know for certain. You should experiment with a sniffing tool both with and without <render> tag to see what the server is sending back as a response body to see any differences. I would also recommend downloading the richfaces source code stepping into into it as well for this experiment.

Comment: @Airduster I need to know what Spring does, preferably without having to try to set it up, as a RichFaces dev I got the other parts covered. (And you don't need a sniffing tool, browsers can display the response just fine)

Comment: Spring <render> tag will return a partial html rendered response of the DOM ID element as defined by the <render fragments="panelGroup"/>. So in your case you would receive something like <div id="panelGroup"><div>etc...</div></div> as a response body

Comment: @Makhiel I updated the question with the response.  I'm debugging to see why the complete section is not included in the response when webflow handles the rendering.

Comment: @ShaneCoder a massive 3 jar major revision upgrade is usually troublesome. If you have a maven project I would make sure that no jars have been downgraded automatically for compatibility reasons in the dependency hierarchy. Yea i'm not familiar enough with jsf or richfaces but that is your problem right there in the response body. You need to figure out what generates that <complete>alert('bob');</complete></extension> and why it is not being generated during the <render fragment="..">

Comment: Which classes in richfaces add the complete tag to the response?

Comment: @ShaneCoder in your log4j.xml (assuming you have one) config file add the following logger  <logger name="org.richfaces"> <level value="debug" /></logger> and try to deduce from the debug output where the response body is being created. From there that should get you closer to isolating the jar/packages the logic is located in.

Comment: You're looking for `org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.renderExtensions()`

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!  I've worked around the issue by moving the fragments to rerender from the flow to the render attribute on the commandButton.  As previously stated, without the render in the flow the oncomplete works.  We like to keep the rendering in the flow, but it doesn't seem worth the effort on this one.